# Can we adjust rate of arrival in a Poisson Process, for a different time interval?

Tags: probability

I am very confused as to how to apply Poisson Process.

Say $\{ X(t) \}$ is a Poisson Process with parameter $\lambda$

So in the time interval $(0,t)$ we say that $$f_X(x)=P(X(t)=x)=
\frac{e^{\lambda t}(\lambda t)^x}{x!}$$

Can we modify this to be in the time interval $(t,t+\delta t)$ by modifying our rate to be $\lambda \delta t$ ?

So in the time interval $(t,t+\delta t)$ we say that $$f_X(x)=
\frac{e^{\lambda \delta t}(\lambda \delta t)^x}{x!}$$

Please clarify any mistakes I am making.

Comment: Yes, in a Poisson counting process, the number of arrivals in a given interval is a Poisson random variable with rate $\lambda$ times the length of the time interval. So the distribution of arrivals between $(t,t+\delta t)$ does not depend on the initial time in which you start counting, $t$, but on the length of the interval $\delta t$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

Yes, the count of events in a Poison Process with rate $\lambda$ is proportional to the length of the interval and not the start of the interval.   Further the counts in *disjoint* intervals are *independent* random variables.

However, the counts in different intervals are *different* random variables, so you should indicate this in some way.

$$\begin{align}f_{\lower{0.5ex}{X(t)}}(x) ~&=~ \mathsf P(X(t)=x) \\[1ex] ~&=~ \dfrac{(\lambda t)^x e^{-\lambda t}}{x!}\\[3ex] f_{\lower{0.5ex}{[X(t+\delta t)-X(t)]}}(y)~&=~\mathsf P(X(t+\delta t)-X(t)=y) \\[1ex] ~&=~\dfrac{(\lambda \delta t)^y e^{-\lambda\delta t}}{y!}\end{align}$$